# JDBC exception while trying to login

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, spring-security

I have a web application where I have been used

```
org.springframework-version: 4.1.4.RELEASE
spring.security.version: 3.2.5.RELEASE
org.hibernate-version: 3.5.1-Final.
java version 1.6
org.postgresql: 7.4.1-jdbc3
```

I'm trying to upgrade the spring, and the hibernate version where I successfully updated the following in my pom file

```
org.springframework-version: 5.3.6
spring.security.version: 5.4.6
org.hibernate-version: 5.4.31.Final
java version 11.0.2
org.postgresql: 42.0.0
```

And I have also updated the related XML file where I mentioned the spring security beans. I'm using Postgres DB. Also, everything is working fine in my system, and when I commit these changes to the QA environment, the login is not working.
I'm checked for the log when logging into the application, and it shows some errors. Here is the log

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 0A000
    [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This method is not yet implemented.
    20210616-02:51:01.539 sitepm-service [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - This method is not yet implemented.

    
        20210616-02:51:01.539 sitepm-admin [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - This method is not yet implemented.
        20210616-02:51:01.542 sitepm-service [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR c.s.a.u.controller.LoginController.setExceptionPage - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
        20210616-02:51:01.542 sitepm-admin [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR c.s.a.u.controller.LoginController.setExceptionPage - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

Checked the Postgres version on the ubuntu server

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-14:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, 42.0.0 is pretty old by now (although your 7.4.1-JDBC3 driver predates it by more than a decade). The current version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver is 42.2.21. Also, it would be helpful if you post the entire stacktrace, not just the exception message, and a [mre].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have updated the exception message which I got while login. Can you please check that and help me, please.

Comment: Your question still does not include an exception stacktrace, nor a [mre]. I really recommend that you upgrade your JDBC driver first to 42.2.22.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, how to check the PostgreSQL JDBC driver version in the ubuntu server

That `org.postgresql` dependency that you upgraded to 42.0.0? That **is** the Postgres JDBC driver. It talks directly to the postgres server running at whatever IP you put in your JDBC URL connection string.

You can check the postgres version (so not the JDBC driver, postgres - the actual database engine) on ubuntu using the command `pg_lsclusters` - you may have to `sudo` it, or run it as user `postgresql`. The first column (with header `Ver`) is listing the DB storage version, which matches with major versions of postgres.

You can also run `psql --version`.

> 20210616-02:51:01.542 sitepm-service [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR c.s.a.u.controller.LoginController.setExceptionPage - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

There is a ton of information missing. There should be a stack trace, there should be an SQLState value (the same value you get from invoking `.getSQLState()` on an `SQLException`), and probably a cause with more information as well.

If this is all you have, you are probably engaging in this extremely bad practice which is regrettably somewhat common amongst newbies, SO answers, and tutorials:

```
try {
   stuff();
} catch (SomeException e) {
   log(e.getMessage());
}
```

Search your codebase for this anti-pattern and delete it all. This is no good. The correct approach to deal with exceptions you can't handle (and most, as in 90%+, of all exceptions cannot be handled) is to throw it onwards. If you can't because of API restrictions, wrap it. Update your IDE templates and the like, because the fire and forget I do not want to think about it solution is this:

```
try {
    stuff();
} catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);
}
```

This will ensure code stops running (this is good - by definition you do not fully understand the exotic conditions that caused this exception to occur, so by definition then you have no idea what you're doing from this point onwards. Therefore, continuing execution is thus running code that wasn't written from the situation at hand - obviously a silly plan) - and ensures all relevant info is retained and should end up in your logs.

Alternatively, find the place where this occurs and log `e.getSQLState()` (which should get logged anyway if you follow my advice above). You can search for that code + 'psql jdbc' and get a much more detailed page on exactly what's going on.

--EDIT--

psql error states are described [on this psql documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

State 0A means: "Feature not supported".

Evidently, hibernate is trying to send some SQL that psql recognizes but doesn't support. You can configure hibernate to print the query, and the SQLException may contain that info as well.

Comment: I have checked the Postgres version on the ubuntu server and updated that on the question(above). Also, I have updated the log above with the SQLState warning which I got while login. Can you please check that.